# Why using a list of elements in selenium won't work but if I use WebDriver it works

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have this code which locate div elements in the dom I used selenium in order to find elements in the HTML page:

```
package com.indeni.automation.ui.model.alerts;

import com.indeni.automation.ui.model.PageElement;
import com.indeni.automation.ui.selenium.DriverWrapper;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import java.util.List;

public class FilterBar extends PageElement {

    private List<WebElement> edgeDropDownMenus = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.dropdown-menu.left"));
    private List<WebElement> middleDropDownMenus = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.combo-menu.left"));

    public FilterBar(DriverWrapper driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    public void clickOnIssuesDropDownMenu(){
        clickButton(edgeDropDownMenus.get(0));
    }
}
```

And this is clickButton function:

```
protected void clickButton(WebElement bthElm){
        bthElm.click();
        printClick(bthElm);
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

but if I am using the following line of code it is working:

```
clickButton(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.dropdown-menu.left")).get(0));
```

But I want to use the first elegant way but I can't figure out why am I getting this error message and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to say that the first approach is not elegant. It is wrong to find the element when the class is initialized. When the class is initialized, those elements were not available. So the list would be basically empty. If you try to access any element from the list, it would throw the exception.

In your second approach, you find the element just before you click on it. That time it presents, so it works. This is the right way to do it.

If you want something elegant, Try something like this. With `FindBy`, we find the element, only when it is required. Not when the class is initialized.  This is elegant and it will also work.

```
public class FilterBar extends PageElement {


    @FindBy(css = "div.dropdown-menu.left" )
    private List<WebElement> edgeDropDownMenus;

    @FindBy(css = "div.combo-menu.left")
    private List<WebElement> middleDropDownMenus;

    public FilterBar(DriverWrapper driver){
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void clickOnIssuesDropDownMenu(){
        clickButton(edgeDropDownMenus.get(0));
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree! thank you for the detailed and well explained answer.